# How can i generate pseudorandom numbers in MATLAB of a specific range

Tags: matlab, random, range

How can i generate 1000 pseudorandom numbers  in range [-0.7,0.7]  and store them in a vector, i've tried different methods but none of them actually worked for me ?

Answer (score 0):

I figurred out the answer myself you can actually do the following

`array = rand(1,1000) * (B - A) + A`

based on that :

`array = rand(1,1000) * 1.4 + 0.7`

will produce the desired vector

Comment: Yeap , fixed !! @LuisMendo

Comment: Welcome to the site!